# What is the source function of seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, machine-learning, seaborn

I am new to data science. I have a question regarding the simple seaborn factorplot. What is the line segment representing?

Here is my test.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

x3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y3 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2]
data = {'x': x3, 'y': y3}
test3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.factorplot(x='Pclass', y='Survived', data=test3)
```

and the result is

[image]

By this simple test, I know that each point in the graph means the mean(exp) of y for all values of x with the same value. For example, when x = 1, we have (1, 0), (1, 3), (1, 3), and (1, 3), so the mean is (0 + 3 + 3 + 3) / 4 = 2.25. However, I don't know why the line segment for x = 1 is from 0.75 to 3.0, why isn't it [0.0, 3.0]?

I tried to find factorplot source or any useful explanation or docu online with no good result.

Can anyone help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this using the "search this repository" search bar at the top of the [github repo](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/master/seaborn).

Searching for "factorplot" led me to `seaborn/categorical.py` and `class _CategoricalPlotter(object)`, which led me to `_BarPlotter(_CategoricalStatPlotter)`, which has docstring """Show point estimates and confidence intervals with bars.""", and it's `__init__` includes  `self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot)`.

The function definition of `estimate_statistic(self, estimator, ci, n_boot)` resides in `class _CategoricalStatPlotter(_CategoricalPlotter)` (still in categorical.py file). There, an empty list `confint` (i.e. confidence interval) is initialized, and filled with:

```
 boots = bootstrap(stat_data, func=estimator,
                                      n_boot=n_boot,
                                      units=unit_data)
 confint.append(utils.ci(boots, ci))
```

So the vertical error bars you mentioned are [bootstrapped confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).